# How do I launch a specific application on a specific desktop in Kubuntu 18.04?

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu, desktop-environments, shortcuts

My Kubuntu 18.04 system has 3 desktops. I like using number 1 desktop for normal activities and desktops 2 and 3 for VMs and other running processes.

I have a shortcut to open a Kali Linux VM. It works and opens the VM, as expected. Once that happens I always move the opened VM to desktop number 2, but that is a manual process. Maintaining the VM on a different desktop helps me keep track on which OS I'm currently using because it can get quite confusing after a few swaps between each.

QUESTION: Is there a way to set the shortcut itself to always launch the application (the VM in this case) on a specific desktop so I don't have to manually do it every time?

Comment: You should use: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/16/auto-move-windows/

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I also use auto-move-windows, but be warned, it has a bug. When it first moves windows, it leaves ghost window images in workspace 1, and you must move to at least one other workspace for it to straighten itself out.

Comment: You mean **workspaces**, not **desktops**.

Comment: Yes @heynnema , you are right. I have also observed the same bug!

Comment: There's just one problem... I use KDE. I didn't mention that on the post because I didn't figure it might be relevant.

Comment: Yes, you **did** say Ubuntu, instead of Kubuntu. You may wish to edit your question, as you'll get different responses. Also change "desktops".

Comment: It's interesting... When I move the active application the context menu clearly says "move to desktop X". Is there a big difference between desktop and workspace? I'm quite new to Linux...

Comment: Kubuntu may, in fact, call them desktops, I stand corrected. Don't use it, so I cant say any further.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure applies to any application.

- Open the application and right-click on the title-bar (or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>)
- A context window opens. In there, choose *More Actions > Specific Application Settings*

[image: Window actions]

- Doing so will open a new window
- In the tab *Size & Position*, click on *Desktop* and then on the dropdown to the immediate right. Make the appropriate choice. *Remember* or *Force* seem appropriate

[image: Edit Application-Specific Settings 1/2]

- Then, click on the next dropdown and choose the desired desktop and click the *Apply* button in the lower right corner (not shown in the image)

[image: Edit Application-Specific Settings 2/2]

You don't have to modify your shortcuts themselves but you need to do this for each application you want to run on specific desktops.

---

The settings you make using the procedure described above are stored in `~/.config/kwinrulesrc` (but this file shouldn't be edited directly by the user).

This rule is to make *gedit* open in desktop #4

```
[1]
Description=Application settings for gedit
clientmachine=kububb
clientmachinematch=0
desktop=4
desktoprule=2
wmclass=gedit
wmclasscomplete=false
wmclassmatch=1
```

and this one is for my virtual machine manager to open on desktop #2:

```
[5]
Description=Application settings for virt-manager
clientmachine=kububb
clientmachinematch=0
desktop=2
desktoprule=2
disableglobalshortcuts=true
disableglobalshortcutsrule=2
wmclass=virt-manager
wmclasscomplete=false
wmclassmatch=1
```

Comment: So It didn't work. I tried options remember, force and apply initially, all to no avail. I used Special Application Settings and also Special Window Settings from the context menu just to make sure.

Comment: It didn't work for any application?

Comment: I've added information on the file that is created/modified when the procedure is used. Do you have such a file? • Another very important point is that your user must be able to write to that file. In other words, that file should be owned by you and not by root. To check that, please open a terminal, and from your home folder, run `find . '!' -user $USER -ls`. Ideally, you should just get back the terminal prompt without any results. If you get some output, it means that such files are owned by *root* which is probably due to misuse of `sudo` or elevated privileges. You need to fix that.